# Codename One How to add BLE extension

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, codenameone

I developed a mobile app using CN1's BLE library. The BLE api did not work after I've added the library that I've downloaded from https://github.com/chen-fishbein/bluetoothle-codenameone, however, I solved this issue by adding the library using CN1's settings/extensions UI instead of manually copying the downloaded libs after I've found the EvSunWoodard's comment here [Codenameone Bluetooth APIs not working on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226601/codenameone-bluetooth-apis-not-working-on-android).

CN1 recently updated and I'm stuck with the same problem after I've added the BLE extension using the new and old settings UI. When I try to call any bluetooth method, the app does not respond and does not catch any exeptions - it simply does nothing. I've noticed that the new settings UI adds a new java package to the impl/stubs library that did not use to be there before the update, I've tried removing this package, as the bluetooth.class file is still there, but this did not have any affect.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get the BLE library working again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most current repo with the bluetoothle lib is https://github.com/codenameone/bluetoothle-codenameone

It is a couple of commits ahead of the fork you used.  It should work for you.
However, it is the same version that you'll get by simply downloading it through Codename One preferences.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded this repo, then built the 'CN1Bluethooth' project and then copied that cn1lib to a new project and it worked. I created an extra new project to test the lib when downloading it using Codename One's preferences, and it did not work, might be missing something silly. JSON works fine when downloading it from the preferences though. Might be worth mentioning i'm using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.  I have built the extension again and added it to CodenameOne preferences.