# Why Location permission are required for Ble scan in android Marshmallow onwards

Tags: android, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy

With the latest release of Android called Marshmallow,Starting a **Bluetooth Low Energy** scan requires permission from Location group.
As a result of that one of the following permissions are required:

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` , `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Any reason why we need to switch on `GPS` for `BLE` scan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Location needs to be enabled for Bluetooth Low Energy Scanning on Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045581/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-6-0)

Comment: This question has correct answer on this thread.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045581/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-6-0

Answer (score 10):

BLE beacons can be used to get location information using nothing more than the BLE broadcast UUID data and an internet connection (e.g. iBeacon, AltBeacon etc.)  Since this is possible and the data can be acquired via scan, a permission for location is required. In reality, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is the required level in order to get `NetworkProvider` level of permission. By using, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` you get `NetworkProvider` as well as GPS.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth permissions let you scan beacons in the foreground without location permissions, but for background scanning you will need location permissions turned on.
if you are adding this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

then 
you will have to use this permission also

```
 <uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION”/>
```

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

see developer guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#setup)