# Xamarin app doesn't recognize any bluetooth device (Plugin.BluetoothLE)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, bluetooth

I am using Plugin.BluetoothLE for making app in combination with arduino project. So for mobile app I am using Xamarin forms and Plugin.BluetoothLE library. Problem is that my mobile device doesn't recognize any bluetooth device. This is my code snippet from view model where I scan devices.

```
private void BtnFindHandler()
{
  if (CrossBleAdapter.Current.Status != AdapterStatus.PoweredOn)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("Bluetooth is not turned on.");
      return;
  }

  if (CrossBleAdapter.Current.IsScanning)
    CrossBleAdapter.Current.StopScan();

  var scanner = CrossBleAdapter.Current.Scan().Subscribe(scanResult =>
  {
    if (scanResult.Device.Name != null)
      Debug.WriteLine(scanResult.Device.Name);
  });
}
```

And this is my Android manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.appname" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true" />
    <application android:label="TestArduino.Android" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"></application>
</manifest>
```

Also in MainActivity.cs, I am asking user explicitly for some some permissions and there is code for that.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
 {
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   base.OnCreate(bundle);

   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
   LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));

   RequestPermissions(new[]
   {
      Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation,
      Manifest.Permission.BluetoothPrivileged
      }, 0);
 }
```

Also I was trying to set manualy permission for my app, but with no success at all.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Just turn on the GPS on your phone. Apparently on some devices just requesting and allowing the location permissions is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the user for the `Location` permission and grant it. Bluetooth permissions in your manifest are enough, no need to ask the user for them.

You can use this [PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) to implement this.

And if you want to know why [there is a debate as if it is a bug or a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44291991)

Comment: I tried to use this plugin and in moment of scanning I have granted permission for Location, but it's still doesn't work.

Comment: @Nenad You can try to grant the permission manually in your phone settings for that application to check.

Comment: Also I tried that, without success. I am going to try with phone older thant Android 6.0 and post my result here. Thank tou for your time.

Comment: @Nenad You may try logging the exceptions in your `Subscribe`

Comment: There is not any kind of exception, just do not recognize any device :(

Comment: @Nenad Please update your question with your new code. Also make sure you are not launching the scan from a background thread.