# Bluetooth Le Gatt Not Finding Any Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

**ANSWER:** Special thanks to Nelson Hoang below for steering me in the right direction and providing valuble resources.  Once the code for adding permissions for locations was added (see Edit2 below) I had to manually go into setting and switch location permissions for the app on.  Once this was done it was working very well.

**Question:** I am attempting to connect to Bluetooth LE devices using the standard Bluetooth LE Gatt from the android studio.  I am forced to update gradle from 2.8 to 2.10 each time.  I've done this automatically and manually on different projects.

However, once I have this app downloaded on my Galaxy S7, it scans and finds nothing despite 3 Bluetooth LE devices broadcasting right next to them.  I know it is not a hardware issue with my S7 because I used Bluefruit LE and was able to pick up signals and connect just fine.  Any solutions?

Edit:  As suggested I will post the scanning code below.  However, none of this was actually written by me.  This is the Bluetooth LE sample code that you can all access from Android Studio.

Edit2: In order to grant the app locatin permissions I added to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

This was in addition to the usual bluetooth packages but it didn't change anything.

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Activity for scanning and displaying available Bluetooth LE devices.
 */
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the scanning code here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have location turned on? Android 6.0+ devices need location to be turned on in order to scan for Bluetooth LE peripherals. [Bluetooth Low Energy startScan on Android 6.0 does not find devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043582/bluetooth-low-energy-startscan-on-android-6-0-does-not-find-devices/33045489#33045489)

Comment: I do have the location on and just tried again.  No luck still.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: It worked!   I had to add code to grant the app permissions and manually give the app location permissions in settings.  Once this was completed it finally started picking up signals!  Thanks again Nelson Hoang!

Answer (score 4):

As per Nelson Hoang's solution above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423244/2585501), these were the modifications that were required to be made to BluetoothLeGatt to get BLE working on Android 6.0+ devices;

1. Manually turn on location services on the Android device
2. Edit BluetoothLeGatt source (android-BluetoothLeGatt-master.zip):

a) In Application - manifests - AndroidManifest.xml,

Add the following line directly above `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>`;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

b) In Application - java - com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt - DeviceScanActivity.java,

i) Add the following code to the import statements;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
```

ii) Add the following code to `public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity`;

```
private static int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private final static String TAG = DeviceScanActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        //Do something based on grantResults
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission denied");
        }
    }
}
```

ii) Edit the `onCreate` function (request location permissions);

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Request Location Permissions:");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    ...
```