# How can I modify BluetoothleGatt to enable BLE device scanning on Android 6.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am new to Android App developing and BLE, and I am learning these using the sample code BluetoothLeGatt [The one I imported from Android Studio]. The code works fine on my tablet (Android 5.0), but the scan activity does not return any BLE devices on Android 6.0. The error message I got is shown below.

```
07-19 12:41:39.615 7617-7642/? W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
                                     java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                         at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.startScan(IBluetoothGatt.java:772)
                                         at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.onClientRegistered(BluetoothLeScanner.java:331)
                                         at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:56)
                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458)
```

I looked at the post [Bluetooth Low Energy startScan on Android 6.0 does not find devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043582/bluetooth-low-energy-startscan-on-android-6-0-does-not-find-devices/33045489#33045489) and the official page [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), but I still don't really know how to modify my code.

I did add the permissions of **GPS**, **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** and **ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**, and I turned on the **Location Service** on my tablet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

But the App still cannot return any BLE devices. Then, when I try to add the following block of code to my App (from ***Requesting Permissions at Run Time*** ), there is always an error on checkSelfPermission [Cannot resolve symbol 'checkSelfPermission']. But I did import `import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;`

Can someone help me with this? Also, is there a simpler answer to the question how to make DeviceScanActivity work?  I don't really know where to put the blocks of the code from ***Requesting Permissions at Run Time*** to my code :(  I know this is a really stupid question, but I am really new to this field. Please help me!

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
}
```

***EDIT***
The following is my dependencies block.

```
dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
}
```

Comment: What SDK level does your application target (as defined in the application's `build.gradle` file)?

Comment: Also, what does your `dependencies` block contain? (Maybe edit these into your question :))

Comment: My target SDK level is 25 in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your responses and help! I've just solved my case!

What I did is that besides adding the permissions in ***AndroidManifest.xml***, I added the following code to my ***onCreate*** method in ***DeviceScanActivity***, and the reference I used is [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html.). Also, I just randomly assigned a number to MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        mHandler = new Handler();
    //Check for permissions
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
        Log.e(TAG, "Permission Status: " +permissionCheck );

    //***********************************************************
    // 
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
            {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } 
            else
            {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
        }

    ......//The rest of code
    }
```

When I first added the above code, there is a pop-up window coming up on my tablet asking me for permissions, and I clicked "allow."
Then, I am able to scan my ble devices.

BTW, it only asks for my permission once. When I clicked "Run Application" later (after slight modifications of my code), it didn't ask for my permission again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add those all permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

It works fine on android 6.0

Comment: Yes, I did! But mine still cannot run :(