# Android BLE Scan never finds devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

Since a few days I try to implement an BLE connection in my APP. I know that the Device, I try to connect with, is full functional, so the problem must be my code.

I use the `BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()` method. 
But the callback Method is never called.

```
   public void startScan() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            isScanning = true;
            Handler mHandler = new Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mainActivityHandler.setMSG("Scan stopped");
                    isScanning = false;
                    leScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_TIME);

            mainActivityHandler.setMSG("Start scan");

            try {

                leScanner.startScan(scanCallback);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mainActivityHandler.catchError(e);
            }

        } else mainActivityHandler.catchError(new Exception("Bluetooth not activated"));
    }
```

My CallbackMethod (dont know if I use gatt correctly, but this is a other question):

```
    private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {


    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        mainActivityHandler.setMSG("Callback");
        isScanning = false;
        try {

            mainActivityHandler.setMSG("Connected to " + results.get(0).getDevice().getName());
            gatt = results.get(0).getDevice().connectGatt(mainActivity, true, bluetoothGattCallback);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor;
            for (int i = 0; i < charIDs.length; i++) {
                gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gatt.getService(serviceID[0]).getCharacteristic(charIDs[i]), true);

                descriptor = gatt.getService(serviceID[0]).getCharacteristic(charIDs[0]).getDescriptor(charIDs[i]);
                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mainActivityHandler.catchError(e);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: do you have the location permissions requested?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Low Energy startScan on Android 6.0 does not find devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043582/bluetooth-low-energy-startscan-on-android-6-0-does-not-find-devices)

Comment: yea, i also have the location activated on my device.

Comment: Can you please post the code of how you are initializing leScanner ?

Comment: did you added ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION , ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Problem

The problem is that you are only overriding the `onBatchScanResults` method and not `onScanResult` method. `onBatchScanResults` will only get triggered if:

1. You have set the `ScanSettings` mode to `ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER` (this is the default) using the `ScanSettings.Builder`.
2. You have set the report delay time to some value >0 using `setReportDelay(long reportDelayMillis)` in your `ScanSettings.Builder`.

> **[reportDelayMillis](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings.Builder.html#setReportDelay(long))** - Delay of report in milliseconds. Set to 0 to be notified of results immediately. Values > 0 causes the scan results to be queued up and delivered after the requested delay or when the internal buffers fill up.

For example:

```
public void startScan(BluetoothLeScanner scanner) {
    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(null).build();

    ArrayList<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
                    filters.add(filter);

    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                                .setReportDelay(1l)
                                .build();

    Log.i(TAG,"The setting are "+settings.getReportDelayMillis());
    scanner.startScan(filters,settings,BLEScan);
}
```

### The Solution

However, you probably just want to get the results once at a time and not a batch of results. To accomplish that, you don't have to modify the ScanSettings, you just need to override the `onScanResult` method in your `ScanCallback` and that will do the trick.

```
private ScanCallback mScanCallback =
        new ScanCallback() {

    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        System.out.println(result.getDevice().getName())
        // Do whatever you want
    };

    ...
};
```

### The Alternative - RxAndroidBle

Anyway, I highly recommend using the library [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/rxandroidble). It is very well maintained and it solves many of the BLE issues out of the box (scanning is maybe the less complicated part in BLE).

Using that library, the scanning can be done like this:

```
Disposable scanSubscription = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(


    new ScanSettings.Builder()
            // .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // change if needed
            // .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) // change if needed
            .build()
        // add filters if needed
)
    .subscribe(
        scanResult -> {
            // Process scan result here.
        },
        throwable -> {
            // Handle an error here.
        }
    );

// When done, just dispose.
scanSubscription.dispose();
```

Comment: Now im connected. Thank you. Little mistake that cost me hours.

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

Do you have the location enabled, make sure it is enabled specially  for devices after Api 23.Also there is a free app nrfconnect (something which I used) Please download it and see it it detects the device.

Also this is what I had used

```
private void startScan() {
        try {
            if (!hasPermissions() || mScanning) {
                return;
            }

            List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
            ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .build();
            mScanResults = new ArrayList<>();
            mScanCallback = new DeviceScanCallback();
            mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            handleProgress(true, getString(R.string.lbl_scanning));
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            mScanning = true;
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (activity == null || !isAdded()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (getResources() != null) {
                        handleProgress(false, getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_scanning));
                        stopScan();
                    }
                }
            }, 20000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.scan_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

// Class to utilize callback

```
     private class DeviceScanCallback extends ScanCallback {

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            try {
                if (result != null && result.getScanRecord() != null && result.getScanRecord().getDeviceName() != null) {
                    Log.d("Device name", "" + result.getScanRecord().getDeviceName());
                    if (result.getScanRecord().getDeviceName().startsWith(ConstantClass.DEVICE_IDENTIFIER)) {
                        addScanResult(result);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            try {
                for (ScanResult result : results) {
                    Log.i("ScanResult - Results", result.toString() + " " + result.getDevice().getName());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "BLE Scan Failed with code " + errorCode);
        }

        private void addScanResult(ScanResult result) {
            try {
                BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
                if (mScanResults != null) {
                    mScanResults.add(device);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes and yes. Code seems to be similar to mine.

Comment: @Proxy So is the nrfConnect app showing the device ? Also for how much time are you scanning it ?

Comment: Can you try to make it 20..just in case...also can you post your code how you are initializing leScanner ? also can you try my code with minor changes and see if it is working ? If it is detecting with nrf means there some mistake in code and not in device.

Comment: Its just my guesswork but I can see you are connecting with gatt too early I suppose and once connected it is probably stopping scan. I would suggest to do the scanning part only at first. Once detected go for connection.