# android BTLE scan callback seemingly not called

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth, btle

I want to run a BTLE scan within a ViewModel. I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it is a good learning experiment for me. I did manage to successfully list my BT devices when running the scan in a more simple setup.

Permissions `BLUETOOTH` `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` are set in the `Manifest`.

I have a `checkPermissions` method in my main settings activity that checks for permissions, and requests permissions if needed. I also have an override for `onRequestPermissionsResult`. The location permissions shows in my app's permissions. Those methods are more or less a copy/paste of open-source projects (see [this](https://github.com/jmas/Android-BLE-Scan-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/joelwasserman/androidbletutorial/MainActivity.java)).

So well, my scan doesn't work. The log in my callback never shows in my logs. There is no error, the only suspicious thing I'm seeing in the logs is this: `D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=12 mScannerId=0`.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```java
interface ScanningStatus {
    void setCurrentlyScanning(boolean updatedStatus);
    boolean getCurrentlyScanning();
}


public class SettingsScanningViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>> mDeviceList;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mInternalDeviceList;
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> mIsScanning;

    private static final String TAG = "viewmodel";

    private BluetoothManager mBtManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBleScanner;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 5000;


    public SettingsScanningViewModel(Application mApplication) {
        super(mApplication);
        mDeviceList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mInternalDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        mIsScanning = new MutableLiveData<>();

        mBtManager = (BluetoothManager) mApplication.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBtAdapter = mBtManager.getAdapter();
        mBleScanner = mBtAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    }


    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>> getBtDevices() {
        return mDeviceList;
    }


    MutableLiveData<Boolean> getScanningStatus() {
        return mIsScanning;
    }


    private void flushList() {
        mInternalDeviceList.clear();
        mDeviceList.setValue(mInternalDeviceList);
    }


    private void injectIntoList(BluetoothDevice btDevice) {
        mInternalDeviceList.add(btDevice);
        mDeviceList.setValue(mInternalDeviceList);
    }


    private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "in callback");
            BluetoothDevice mDevice = result.getDevice();
            if (!mInternalDeviceList.contains(mDevice) && mDevice.getName() != null) {
                injectIntoList(mDevice);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScanFailed: " + errorCode);
        }
    };


    private ScanningStatus scanningStatus = new ScanningStatus() {
        @Override
        public void setCurrentlyScanning(boolean status) {
            mIsScanning.setValue(status);
        }

        public boolean getCurrentlyScanning() {
            return mIsScanning.getValue();
        }
    };


    void doBtScan() {
        Log.d(TAG, "flush list first");
        flushList();
        Log.d(TAG, "starting scan with scanCallback " + scanCallback);
        scanningStatus.setCurrentlyScanning(true);
        mBleScanner.startScan(scanCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "scan should be running for " + SCAN_PERIOD);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            mBleScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
            scanningStatus.setCurrentlyScanning(false);
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
    }
}
```

I am really not sure what is wrong. Is it because I'm creating new `BluetoothManager`, `BluetoothAdapter` and `BluetoothLeScanner` in my ViewModel compared with the main activity where I initiate and request permissions? If so, how could I re-use these same objects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OKKKKKKKKKKKK another instance of trying to find out what's wrong for hours, posting, then 2mn later finding out by myself.

Looks like `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` is not enough and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is needed. So I suppose I must be using a different SDK than previously!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These three steps worked for me.

1. GPS should be turned on (write some code to turn it on if not already).
2. both ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions should be declared in manifest and asked at runtime.
3. and the most important is the below answer talking about ScanSettings

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831870/10432212