# Android 10 Bluetooth LE Scan Issues

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-10.0, bluetoothlescanner

I am trying to get a simple Bluetooth LE Scanning app working under Android 10

The Scan starts but does not discover the devices.

There is a lot of traffic about correct permissions needed for Android 10 and I think I have them correct, Currently, I am requiring and asking the user for:

BLUETOOTH
BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
FOREGROUND_SERVICE
ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

The app is simple, just a single form, a start scan button, a stop scan button and a textview to show the results.

Can someone point out what i have missed?

Many thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;

Button startScanningButton;
Button stopScanningButton;
TextView peripheralTextView;


private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);


    peripheralTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PeripheralTextView);
    peripheralTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    startScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartScanButton);
    startScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startScanning();
        }
    });

    stopScanningButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopScanButton);
    stopScanningButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopScanning();
        }
    });
    stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("This app needs background location access");
                    builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @TargetApi(23)
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since background location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons in the background.  Please go to Settings -> Applications -> Permissions and grant background location access to this app.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }

            }
        } else {
            if (!this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            }
            else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons.  Please go to Settings -> Applications -> Permissions and grant location access to this app.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }

        }
    }


    final BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

    btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

    if (btAdapter == null || !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }


    btScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

}


// Device scan callback.
private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + "\n");
    }
};

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                System.out.println("fine location permission granted");
            } else {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover devices when in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void startScanning() {
    peripheralTextView.setText("");
    peripheralTextView.append("Start Scanning");
    startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
        }
    });
}

public void stopScanning() {
    peripheralTextView.append("Stopped Scanning");
    startScanningButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    stopScanningButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: For BLE, you should only need `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` from what I am seeing. However, you need to wait to get permission first. Right now, you may be making `requestPermission()` calls, but you are then proceeding to do your scan. `requestPermissions()` is not a blocking call -- you will not have permission yet when it returns.

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013818/bluetoothlescanner-startscan-with-android-6-0-does-not-discover-devices

Answer (score 2):

It seems Bluetooth scanning is disable. Please find below screenshot. Only location enable will not work along with location you need to enable Bluetooth scanning.

[image: Bluetooth Scanning]

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit to late but I hope this help someone.

Those permissions are correct. You are not enabling **location services** and that's your issue.

Take a look at [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37065090). As you can see there is a lot of discussion about the why Google make the things that way. At the very end of the issue, there is a Youtube video link (see it [here](https://youtu.be/D2cU_itNDAI?t=1286)) where **Chet** explained that even Google not know what is like that, so they added a new permission in A12.

Also

> Android 10 permissions:
> On Android 10, you generally must have obtained
> ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION for beacon detection to work when your app
> is not visible. However, it is possible to scan with only foreground
> location permission granted and a foreground service if you add
> android:foregroundServiceType="location" to your foreground service
> declaration in the manifest. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates) for details.

So, enabling location services will be enough to get your results with

```
bluetoothMangaer.adapter.startScan(scanCallback)
```

In the case you dont want the user to enable his location, you can do a

```
bluetoothMangaer.adapter.startDiscovery()
```

Comment: Talk about frustrating!  I've been trying to scan BLE from a service for two days now and finally found your little nugget of helpfulness.   Solved my problem with a single permission, ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION.  Thank you, Alex Rivas!

Comment: Is always a pleasure helping other people :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was something to do with the adapter itself causing the problem, looking at logcat I was getting a status=133 on the startscanning call, resetting the physical adapter cleared the issue and scan results began appearing

Comment: what do you mean by resetting the adapter ?? is there any method available ?